# adding webapi to an mvc app - routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc app with this routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


}
```

and my controllers are accessible at:

```
http://localhost:1234/Test/Version
```

Now, I want to add a web api to this mvc app.
Let's say it's called TestWebAPIController
however, I cannot access it at

```
http://localhost:1234/TestWebAPI
```

or

```
http://localhost:1234/TestWebAPI/Get
```

How can I fix this?
I already tried changing the route to

> url: "{controller}/{id}",...

**Update:**
I tried adding a WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and tried adding

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

to the Global.asax.cs
but I'm getting syntax errors...
In WebConfig.cs, it complains about:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

and says does not contain definition for MapHttpAttributeRoutes
and in Global.asax.cs, it complains about

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

and says System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration does not contain a definition for 'Configure'

**Update:**
After installing webapi:

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

the errors went away but I still cannot route to my webapi.

**Update:**
Finally got it working.
In the global.asap.cs, you MUST put the webapi route **BEFORE** the mvc routing as this:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Also needed to change:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

to

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Comment: Did you add Web API nuget package?

Comment: Also, this is really turning into 2 separate questions. Original question about routing is sorted at this point in both of the answers below.

Comment: I needed to intall WebApi.WebHost...I'm not getting errors any more but back to the original problem. It does not route.

Comment: if you are calling `http://localhost:1234/TestWebAPI` then you won't be routed properly.  if you are using the route templates shown in this question you should be calling `ttp://localhost:1234/api/TestWebAPI`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your steps to get it working. I really needed this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API does not use the same routes as MVC. If you start a new project in Visual Studio for Web API, or include Web API, you'll see a file called WebApiConfig.cs under the App_Start folder. This is where your Web API routes go. Those routes are registered via the `Register()` method of this class, using the `HttpConfiguration` object that is passed in:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //other stuff

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Notice that I've prepended the route with "api/v1/" as well. This, or something similar, is typically a good practice so that you can version your api as needed without affecting code that uses the legacy api.

Comment: Thanks. What I want to know is how to add it then? Do I need a separate project or is it possible to add a separate routing config and load it additionally?

Comment: @max you can add the code to an existing project no problem. However, it's enough code that it doesn't make sense to post here. I'd recommend starting an new web project in Visual Studio and including only Web API so you can see what's being created. Off the top of my head I *think* all the pertinent code is contained in WebApiConfig.cs and Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 1):

Web Api routes are registered to HttpConfiguration.  Web Api does not share the same route collection as the MVC part of your project.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

if you are calling `http://localhost:1234/TestWebAPI` then you won't be routed properly. if you are using the route templates shown in this question you should be calling `http://localhost:1234/api/TestWebAPI`